# LNK2005 файл уже определен

Tags: c++

Не могу понять почему выдается ошибка и как ее исправить.

Основной файл:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "functions.cpp"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float Arr1[3][3];
    float Arr2[3][3];
    CinArray(Arr1,3,3);
    CinArray(Arr2, 3, 3);
    CoutArray(Arr1, 3, 3);
    CoutArray(Arr2, 3, 3);
}
```

Функции которые пытаюсь инклуднуть:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void CinArray(float Arr1[3][3], int nRow, int nCol) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nRow; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < nCol; j++) {
            cout << "a[" << i << "," << j << "] = ";
            cin >> Arr1[i][j];
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void CoutArray(float Arr1[3][3], int nRow, int nCol) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nRow; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < nCol; j++) {
            cout << Arr1[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Выдает ошибки:

```
LNK2005 "void __cdecl CinArray(float (* const)[3],int,int)" (?CinArray@@YAXQAY02MHH@Z) уже определен в functions.obj
```

```
LNK2005 "void __cdecl CoutArray(float (* const)[3],int,int)" (?CoutArray@@YAXQAY02MHH@Z) уже определен в functions.obj
```

```
LNK1169 обнаружен многократно определенный символ - один или более
```

Comment: Через include нужно подключать не файл с реализациями, а файл с заголовками функций и объявлением классов (h или hpp). Судя по ошибке, у вас модуль functions.cpp собирается в объектный файл и линкуется к объектному файлу основного модуля, и дополнительно вы его инклудите в основной файл - в итоге у вас функции из functions.cpp задвоены.

Comment: Смотрите - вверху есть такое поле "Поиск". Если в него ввести краткое описание вашей проблемы - на просто **LNK2005** - то вы увидите [массу ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=LNK2005). Учитесь эффективно использовать Интернет...